# Create A Chart On Each Worksheet Using The Data From That Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am in needs of creating a chart for each worksheet in my workbook (roughly 10, but could be 12) - I recorded a macro, and added in the syntax I have used before to iterate workbooks and have come up with the below.  Now my issue that I see right off the bat is that the syntax specifies `Chart 1` and once that name has been used it can not be re-used.

How would this syntax be altered in order to make it re-usable for inserting the exact same chart on multiple worksheets in a workbook?

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim WS_Count As Integer, I As Integer

  WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Range("A1:I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$I$2")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.9416666667, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.4531248177, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 205
  Next I
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
The workbook has roughly 10 worksheets in it, each worksheet contains the data for the chart in A1:I2 - I need to graph that data on each individual worksheet.

Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

Just **not sure** where you want the Chart's source suppose to be from, are they all from `Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$I$2")`, from "Sheet1" ? or from their sheet ?

```
Sub CreateChart()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Chart As Shape

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     Set Chart = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)

     With Chart
        .Chart.SetSourceData ws.Range("$A$1:$I$2")
        .ScaleWidth 1.9416666667, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
        .ScaleHeight 1.4531248177, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
        .Chart.ClearToMatchStyle
        .Chart.ChartStyle = 205 ' why do you have this line ? why not define the chart style as 205 in the first line ?
     End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error: Method or data member not found on the line .SetSourceData

Comment: @YohanGreenburg  have u tried the edited code ? Is it working as u intended ?

Comment: With your edited code on the line reading `ActiveChart.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.9416666667, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight` it gives me an error of: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
The item with the specified name wasn't found

Comment: And the charts source comes from their own sheet as that is where the chart should be created.

Comment: @YohanGreenburg I've modified the code, copy the entire code, and let me know (worked in my tests)